# Finding disc of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find the disc of convergence 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n^{3}}$$
I have applied the ratio test but I can not seem to come up with a conclusion.

Comment: Try Cauchy test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing with $\sum z^n$, you see that the series is absolutely convergent for $|z|<1$.

On the other hand, the series fails to converge for $z=1$.

Comment: Why not $z=1$? Seems to be the simplest point with lack of convergence.

Comment: @lisyarus: Because I'm overcomplicating it. Of course that is better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difficulty with the ratio test:  $\frac{z^{(n+1)^2}}{z^{n^2}}= \frac{z^{n^2+ 2n+ 1}}{z^{n^2}}= z^{2n+ 1}< 1$.
For what z is that always true, and, in particular, for n going to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

Apply root test. Though $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ doesn't exist, $\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty} (a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ exists and the value is 1, where $a_n$ is $n$th coefficient term of given series.